# Question regarding Herbrand's Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The Herberand theorem states that for universal sentence $\varphi$ over a first-order language $\Sigma$
without $"="$ (identity) and with at least one constant:

> $\varphi$ is satsifiable iff $\varphi$ is satisfiable in some Herbrand structure over $\Sigma$

My question is:

Assuming that $\varphi$ itself does not contain $"="$ and has at least one constant but $\Sigma$ does contain $"="$:

> 1. Does the statement still holds if $\Sigma$ is finite?

> 2. Does the statement still holds if $\Sigma$ is infinite?

Struggling to understand why is it required to not have equality.

Comment: You can see Chin-Liang Chang & Richard Char-Tung Lee, [Symbolic Logic and Mechanical Theorem Proving (Academic Press, 1973)](https://books.google.it/books?id=oGriBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), **Ch.8 Equality**.